# How can I put my J2ME application in mobile?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile

I have created a J2ME application in the NetBeans IDE.
Now I want put/install this application on my mobile device.
How can I do this?

Comment: Bluetooth the jar file to your phone or send it via USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

First you copy the your project's .jad and .jar files into your mobile. Then click the .jad file in your mobile. Then install it. Then the application is ready for executing in your mobile.

Answer (score 0):

The only universal answer to this question is: stick the jad and jar online somewhere and visit the jad's URL in the handset's browser.

However some handsets may install the JAR successfully if you send it via bluetooth.  Many handsets also let you install MIDlets using USB cable in conjunction with the device's PC Suite or equivalent software.

Comment: is that posible to create a jar file by netbeans?

Comment: Right, didn't realise your question was quite so fundamental.  Your real question sounds like "How do I compile and build a midlet within Netbeans?"...  never used it so don't know.

Comment: Mind,Yes you can create a jar,jad file using netbeans,eclipse etc.But they need the j2me plugins.After installing j2me plugins.After coding your project (midlet).Then search there is any option for packgage.Using the package menu you can create jad,jar,etc